# Window in cypher

Tags: neo4j

So basically it comes down to this. I have a `(:PERSON)` that used his `(:CAR)` at a given `(:TIME)`. This triplet is fully connected. It might be that a `(:CAR)` is used by other `(:PERSON)` and a `(:PERSON)` can use multiple `(:CAR)` all of that at different `(:TIME)`.

What I want to query is that for each combination `(p:PERSON)-[:AT]-(t:TIME)` I want the number of cars used in `t-6H` (`p-[:USED]-(c:CAR)-[:AT]-(o:TIME)` in `t-6H`).

Here is what I have achieved so far, but this only takes each `:PERSON` once.

`MATCH (n:PERSON)-[:AT]-(t:TIME)
WITH n,t
MATCH (n)-[:USED]-(c:CAR)-[:AT]-(o:TIME)
WITH n,t,c,toFLoat(t.id) as current, toFloat(o.id) as previous 
WITH n,t,c,current-previous as diff
WHERE (diff) >= 0 AND (diff) <= 3600*6
WITH n, count(distinct c) as cnt
RETURN n, cnt`

Where `:TIME(id)` is a String containing the time in seconds

Hope this is clear. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should count on person and 't' :

```
MATCH (n:PERSON)-[:AT]-(t:TIME)
WITH n,t
MATCH (n)-[:USED]-(c:CAR)-[:AT]-(o:TIME)
WITH n,t,c,toFLoat(t.id) - toFloat(o.id) as diff 
WHERE (diff) >= 0 AND (diff) <= 3600*6
WITH n,t, count(distinct c) as cnt
RETURN n,t, cnt
```

Also you should make your TIME(id) a numeric value so you can remove the toFloat from your query which will improve the performance.

Comment: Seems to do the work. I'll double check and mark it as resolved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put your t Time in your USED relation.

Either you'll want only one USED per Person + Car then have a collection of times (no nice for querying)

or you'll have multiple USED

Comment: I do understand the idea but the thing is that the time is needed in other queries (in addition to the fact that the query above will be refactored to meet other needs). We thus pushed the TIME as a node instead of a property. This was easier to maintain and updating every relation.

Comment: Sorry but if two persons use the same three cars, how do you know who used which and when ? Moreover no usage duration in your model.